# (HTML) How to save conent of text area to a local variable?

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to save the content of a `textarea` to a local variable. Those variables are used on a Java method that send their values to a Database upon a button click. But I can't seem to do it right. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OFLG.jpg 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv9Yb.jpg (this is my method that updates the DB with the values user puts on `textarea`)

The variables are inside the black box. They are Strings.

Comment: For sharing code, you should include the relevant sections inline in your question.

Comment: The code in your pictures appears to be Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: The relevant sections might be the whole code :p but thank you very much for replaying. im trying to explain myself better.
Some user types in a textarea. the clicks the submit button. when he clicks, the content of that textarea needs to be stored into a string. that string is then used as a parameter on a method called to update some values on the database. i dont know if i could make myself clear. Thank you all for your attention

Answer (score 0):

frankly, I've no idea how your jsp part <% balabala %> is working. However, without javascript, I dont think it's possible to send value of a textarea out of the Form when this form is triggered. You can tried to move the textarea inside the form you want to post, and, the name ***noticia*** is not consistant with the Java method parameter, which may leads to that the Java method could not find the right value.

Comment: Ill try to explain myself better. forget about the pictures. Lets say some user types in a textarea. then clicks the submit button. when he clicks it, the content of that textarea needs to be stored into a string. that string is then used as a parameter on a method that is called by that same button to update some values on the database. i dont know if i could make myself clear. Thanks in advance for your attention

Comment: Let's make it even simpler. First, this action is not as easy as you described. You should split it into 2 steps: a) is post data into servlet, b) is DB update. While the key of 1st step is a good welformed data, like http://localhost/test?name=test&age=25. an input/select/textarea with proper name attribute(name or age in my example) is mandatory. for b), I believe you know how to make it.